# MS Projects show task always in timesheet

Tags: ms-project, tasks, task-management, ms-project-2016

I am currently using Microsoft projects 2016 with time sheets. How can i create a task which is always shown in my time sheet with 0 planned work time? I have administrative tasks beside my project tasks which I can't plan on an explicit date. I have already tried to do this with an administrative time category, but this is shown for every user. Is this currently supported? How could I implement this feature by myself through an add on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround for this. You can create a task with any duration (for example from 01.10.2016 to 31.12.2100) and with a total work amount of 0.1 hours. Projects will plan 0 hours every day for this duration and the task is always shown in your timesheet.

Creating the task:

[image: Creating the task]

Appears in your timesheet:

[image: Timesheet]